# Java Eclipse WindowBuilder Planet Animation

Tags: java, user-interface, animation, timer, windowbuilder

I'm currently making a little game and I'm using the WindowBuilder plugin for eclipse to help save some time. Essentially the game is turn based and so when I click the advance button, I would like to have a little animation of my planet image, which makes it fully rotate.

I have tried to get to grips with various ways of animating this but currently nothing has worked. I've tried to simply put the thread to sleep then change the image, which works for one frame, but I have yet to work out how to make an animation consisting of multiple frames. I also tried a timer but that hasn't worked either.

```
btnAdvanceYear.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            // Here is where the animation will go:
            // Something like this is what I'm trying to get to work:

            try {
                lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jack\\Pictures\\planet2.png"));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jack\\Pictures\\pplanett.png"));
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    });
```

Of course there'll be more than two frames.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Consider using paintComponent and Graphics